# Steering wheel cracking like old ship

Tags: power-steering, steering-wheel, fiesta, power-steering-fluid

I have a 2007 ford fiesta. I had the steering gear replaced. The power steering is somewhat better but still there is this cracking noise when turning the wheel when stationary.
Link with the noise.
https://streamable.com/pc59hz

What the heck this might be?

Comment: Was it making this same noise before you had the steering gear replaced?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: If the front end is in the air and you turn the steering wheel, do you hear the same noise? Did you replace the steering rack, or did a shop? If a shop, did they say what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say from here exactly what is making the noise with any certainty. Could be a worn bushing or mount or just a rubber part that needs a spray with silicone.

A worthwhile mechanic will diagnose an issue before replacing expensive parts. The next mechanic who proposes to repair or replace something to stop this noise needs to answer this question: Will you guarantee that the repair that you propose will fix this problem, yes or no? If the answer is no, either pay for more diagnostic time or find a different mechanic.

Diagnosis is not cheap. It takes time and expertise. But in the long run it's far less expensive both in direct cost and in your own precious time and aggravation to pay for diagnosis than to pay a parts-changer to take a wild guess at your expense. Sometimes you get lucky, but this Stack is littered with stories of victims who fell for the quick cheap fix gambit and lost.

Comment: The mechanic was saying something about spraying the strut bearing.

Comment: @Bufer That's plausible. On my car the strut bearing is surrounded by a rubber donut that pivots slightly inside a steel dome, and it's plausible that the rubber could be creaking against the steel. But it will take some time ($$) to safely expose the rubber parts for lubrication. Will the mechanic guarantee that this will fix the noise? I don't need to know, but you need to ask. And then ask why you paid for steering gear replacement if this was the problem all along . . . .